# Is TDBCtrlGrid a generic data aware component?

Tags: delphi, bde

I am planning to move away from BDE and dBase so, while implementing some application I need to stay away from everything that could make the transition more difficult. I wonder, for instance, if data aware components like TDBCtrlGrid is  toot tied in some way to the BDE or not.

Comment: It is not tied to the BDE but it is a horribly glitchy control and you should avoid using it. Do you have to move away to ditch BDE? No. But in future plan to replace it with something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Db-aware components like the TDBCtrlGrid, TDBGrid, TDBEdit, etc, should all work fine with more modern TDataSet-descendants than TQuery, TTable, etc.  So the answer to your q is that they are all generic.

The whole point of the design of Delphi's db-aware components is that the access model they use is abstracted from any particular dataset implementation and so will work with any TDataSet descendant, because TDataSet itself implements an abstracted data-access model.

Delphi's db-aware components work at two steps removed from TDataSet, and interact with it (or any descendant of it) via TDataSource and TDataLink and its descendants.  All data interactions occur via TDataLinks - see the source in DB.Pas.

Comment: I think this is exactly the answer I needed. Another matter is how bad or food a specific data aware component is.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no : `TDBCtrlGrid` is not tied to the BDE.

`TDBCtrlGrid` is populated by a "dataset" or, if you prefer, by a [`TDataSet`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet.html) which is an abstract class providing the basic properties, events, and methods for working with data.

There are many implementations of `TDataSet` which will allow you to use whatever data base engine you want.

From the doc here are some popular `TDataSet` implementations :

> - TCustomADODataSet is the base class for datasets that access their
>     data using ActiveX Data Objects (ADO). TCustomADODataSet descendants
>     include TADODataSet, TADOTable, TADOQuery, and TADOStoredProc.
>     Developers who create custom dataset components that use ADO derive
>     them from CustomADODataSet.
> - TIBCustomDataSet is the base class for datasets that directly access
>     the data in InterBase tables. TIBCustomDataSet descendants include
>     TIBDataSet, TIBTable, TIBQuery, and TIBStoredProc. Developers who
>     create custom dataset components that directly access data in an
>     InterBase database derive from TIBCustomDataSet.
> - TCustomSQLDataSet is the base class for unidirectional datasets.
>     Unidirectional datasets are read-only datasets that permit only
>     forward navigation. TCustomSQLDataSet descendants include the
>     dbExpress datasets TSQLDataSet, TSQLQuery, TSQLTable, and
> - TSQLStoredProc. Developers who create custom dataset components that
>     use dbExpress to access their data derive from TCustomSQLDataSet.
> - TCustomClientDataSet is the base class for in-memory datasets. Client
>     datasets can work with data from files on disk or with data provided
>     by another component via a provider. They cache that data in memory,
>     maintain a record of any changes in a change log, and apply cached
>     updates at a later point back to the source of the data. Developers
>     who create custom datasets that store their data in an in-memory cache
>     derive from TCustomClientDataSet.

Answer (score -2):

I would investigate several databases including some of the latest in the Delphi version you currently use. That includes Mongo if you have the latest.

For productivity Firedac is quite good. It codes like ADO and performs almost as well as GO.

In general I suggest getting Nick Hodges' book and start using Spring4D.

If that is too deep for you then Firedac is a good starting point.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question he asked which is about the user interface data aware controls layer not the data access layer.